# View documentation of Java inside of emacs

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, java, lsp-ui

I want to view Java documentation like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/ inside emacs.

I have tried lsp-java with lsp-ui but my setup wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation for `lsp-ui` yet? When you do, you will find a quick summary of the features in the README file. This includes [information about `lsp-ui-doc`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-ui#lsp-ui-doc), with nice screenshots of the several ways that it can show the documentation. It also includes a short list of variables that you can customize. First amongst these is `lsp-ui-doc-enable`, which does exactly what you think it does. Use `M-x customize-variable` to toggle it. You can use `M-x customize-group` to customize the `lsp-ui-doc` group, which will show you all of the variables it uses.

Comment: Yes I have read (default value of `lsp-ui-doc-enable` is t). The problem is that for a a simple `System.out.println(...)` only `void java.io.PrintStream.println(...)` is shown, not a full documentation of the behavior of the method.

Comment: like here [https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println())

Comment: Do you know for certain that `lsp-java` provides that level of detail to `lsp-ui-doc`?

Comment: this video at 1:15 does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yah69AfYP34

Comment: Then use the configuration shown in the video.